# How to combine a List[List[String],Int] to a single List[String] in Scala?

Tags: scala, list, maps

The list I am getting is by converting it to list from a  map, which looks like this

```
Map((List(3,0,Blank,20) <- 53, (List(10,Blank,392,000) <- 53),(List(3,8,08,31) <- 1))
```

my list is like

```
List((List(3,0,Blank,20),53), (List(10,Blank,392,000),53),(List(3,8,08,31),1))
```

My expected output is

```
List((List(3,0,Blank,20,53),List(10,Blank,392,000,53),List(3,8,08,31,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your every object contains `List` and `Int` element so you can make easily map:

```
val list = List((List(3,0,Blank,20),53), (List(10,Blank,392,000),53),(List(3,8,08,31),1))

list.map(elem => elem._1 :+ elem._2)
```

Output from this should be like you want

If you'll receive `List[Any]` you need to convert `Int` to `String` so only one change `elem._2.toString`

Comment: also, how to append a List[String] toList[List[String]] -> the new list should be added as final position in list of list.Like list[String] = ["A","B","C","D"], List[List[String]] = List[List[1,2,3,4],List[3,4,4,4], List[5,5,5,6], List[8,8,8,7]] ... Expected => List[List[1,2,3,4,"A"], List[3,4,4,4,"B"], List[5,5,5,6,"C"], List[8,8,8,7,"D"]]

Comment: Using adding element method so `val newList = oldList :+ List(8, 8, 8 ...)` if you want to change existing list you need to use mutable list and similar method

Comment: this adds lists to the end, but my requirement is new list has to be appended as a part of existing list as last element.

Comment: Look at the documentation: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html To append element you must usee `+:` instead